# Changing CSS across all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to swap between two different style sheets and keep the style being selected on the home page but keeping the use consistent throughout all the pages.

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  }
</script>

<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('style.css')">Blue</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('style1.css')">White</button>
```

This only changes the style sheet for the homepage, but how do I apply this change to all the other pages in the website?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the local storage to store the current stylesheet.

```
var stylesheet = localStorage.getItem("stylesheet");

function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    localStorage.setItem('stylesheet', sheet);
}

if(stylesheet) {
    swapStyleSheet(stylesheet)
}
```

Comment: The first line throws up an error: 'the operation is insecure'